# Fail to pass array into function. Why isn't working?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C Programming, and I need help on this.
There are no errors nor any warnings on this c code, but I can't seem to get the array to pass the values into the calcMagicNumber function. How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function prototypes
void printHeader ();                   
void askForNumber();                    
int calcMagicNumber(int num[], int size ); 
void writeResults(char*, int, int);    
void goodbye();                        

int main (){
    //assign the variables
    char name[51];                    //for user to input name
    char option='Y';                  //option for user to continue the program
    int magicNumber=0;                //to calculate the magic number
    int flag=0;      //to determine if the magic number is an even or odd number
    int num[5]={0,0,0,0,0};                 //for user to input the 5 numbers

    printHeader();

    puts("Please enter your name");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", name);


    do{

        //call the function calcMagicNumber to produce the magic number
        magicNumber = calcMagicNumber(num, 5);

        //determine if the magic number is an even number
        if(magicNumber%2==0){
            flag=1;
        }
        else{
            flag=0;
        }

        //call function writeResults to print out the user's name, the magic 
number and whether the magic number is even
        writeResults(name, magicNumber, flag);

        fflush(stdin); //clear buffer

        //ask user if he or she would like to go again
        puts("Would you like to go again? [y/n]");
        scanf("%c", &option);

        option = toupper(option); //to convert the user's input into capital 
letters

    }while(option == 'Y');

    goodbye();

    return 0;
}

//function bodies
void printHeader (){
    //print out name and chapter 3 - magic number
    printf("Chapter 3- Magic Number \n");
    printf("Tan Su Fern\n\n");
}

void askForNumber(){
    int i=1;
    int num[5]={0,0,0,0,0};

    //ask user to input number
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){

        puts("Please enter a number.");
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);   

    }
    num[i]=i;
    printf("\n%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", num[1], num[2], num[3], num[4], num[5]);
}

int calcMagicNumber(int num[], int size ){
    int magicNumber=0;

    //call askForNumber function for user to input 5 numbers
    askForNumber();

    printf("\n%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", num[1], num[2], num[3], num[4], num[5]);
    //calculate the magic number based on the numbers input by the user
    magicNumber = (num[1]*num[5])-(num[2]+num[3]+num[4]);

    return magicNumber;
}

void writeResults(char* name, int magicNumber, int flag){
    //print out the magic number and the user's name
    printf("\nHi %s , your magic number is %d.\n", name, magicNumber);

    //print out if the magic number is an even or odd number
    if(flag==1){
        printf("This is an even number.\n\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("This is an odd number.\n\n");
    }
}

void goodbye(){
    //say goodbye
    printf("goodbye");
}
```

Comment: You *do* remember that array indexes start with *zero*?

Comment: Exactly what's going wrong? What result are you expecting and what results are you getting? How did you conclude that the values aren't being passed?

Comment: Also, calling `fflush` with an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly marked as *undefined behavior* in the C specification. Some systems add it as an extension, but generally you should not do it.

Comment: @lurker This program needs to get 5 numbers from the user, and then use the 5 numbers to produce a "magic number" by using a formula.
I use the array to store the 5 numbers, then pass it to another function calcMagicNumber to calculate the "magic number". However, the stored value in the array failed to pass to that function and that results in the "magic number" to become 0 everytime.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okayy so what should I use if not for the fflush(stdin) ? And I don't really get the indexes starts with 0 thingy. Like how does that affect the c code?

Comment: If you declare an array, `int num[5];`, then the values are `num[0]`, `num[1]`, ..., `num[4]`. That's what's meant by index starts at 0. `num[5]` is an invalid reference. See your standard C manual for details. The `num` array is being passed, but you are not accessing the values in the array correctly. C will not warn you or give you an error at compile time. At run time, it may or may not give an error unless it's accessing memory your program has no right to access.

Comment: Just a side note: You *can* have it shorter (if you like): `flag = magicNumber%2 == 0;`

Comment: @Aconcagua  I set the values in the array to 0 so that it does not take any garbage value. There is a code at the later part where I ask the user to input the values into the array. 

And thanks for the side note! =)

Comment: @Suzy Have a look at Dude's/Lurker's comments again: indices of arrays start at 0! So your for loop must look like this: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {/*...*/}`. Problems of your variant: 1. You leave `num[0]` at 0, if involved in multiplication, result will be 0, 2. (worse!) you access `num[5]`, which is beyond your array bounderies -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Aconcagua Okay. I've changed the for loop to the one you suggested, and i also got got rid of the num[5]. (changed them into num[0]...num[4].
But still, the program does not seem to be really working.

Comment: @lurker Hmm what's the correct way of accessing the values in the array correctly?

Comment: I believe I showed exactly how to access them in my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is a second array within your function `askForNumber`

```
void askForNumber()
{
    int num[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    //  ^^
}
```

This second array co-exists to the one defined in main as long as you are within the function, but will be destroyed again as soon as you leave the function. The values of the user will be assigned to this second array, while the first one remains untouched.

Instead, you need to pass main's array (the one you passed to calcMagicNumber) further to askForNumber:

```
void askForNumber(int num[], size_t size)
{
    // int num[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    //     ^^ drop this one!
}
```

Side note: In C (this is different to C++), a function not accepting any parameters actually is declared/defined as:

```
void f(void);
//     ^^^^
```

Leaving out the void keyword makes it possible to pass arbitrary number of parameters to the function. Try this:

```
void good(void) { }
void bad() { }

int main()
{
    good();
    bad(1);
    bad(1, 2, 3);
    good(1); // <- this is the ONLY line that won't compile...
}
```

The `void f()` syntax is a remainder of pre-ANSI C times where function parameters where declared afterwards. Prefer not to use this syntax any more.

Comment: Okayy I understand what's wrong now. 
Thank you so much, it worked!!

And thanks for the side note too!! I learned a lot today haha

Comment: @Suzy If this answer answers your question, [you should accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).